# Control another android app from my App interface

Tags: java, android, android-studio, root

Here is the deal:

I want to make a **Live Display** feature, for my ElePhone p8000. I know there is Live Display feature already implemented, but its not working. Instead of that it has an app called **MiraVision** in which you can manually set modes. Like, when outside is bright u set the mode to outside, and u can clearly see everything on the display. In evenings u have to manually set it (**again**), on night mode, so it doesn't hurt your eyes.

Anyways, I want to build an APP that will have an option for LiveDisplay ON/OFF. When it's **on**, it will keep record of the **clock**, so when its **day** the brightness will be **high**, and when its **night** it will go **dark**, and change modes in the **MiraVision app respectively.**

I have experience in C++, C# programming, and a little bit in Java. So first of all I want to know is this possible? (**i think it definitely is**), and if you can give me any kind of help (tutorials, posts..whatever you think its helpful)

**Thanks!**